# My variables wont save in the array, they get replaced? help me

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to save my variables in an array. Theses variables are written in by the user and saved to localStorage when a button is pressed. On my other html page i reach these variables and put them in 3 different arrays(the variables, that go in three arrays). Then the user writes in new text and save to the variables. Now to the problem. The newly created variables don't add to the array, they replace. I'm thinking this is due to to the same variable name however I can't find an solution.

I have tried to change variable names etc for saving the new variable but cant find solution.

```
//This is html page 2 (gets the items from localhost)
var TankaKostnadVar = localStorage.getItem("StorageKostnadVar");
var TankaLiterVar= localStorage.getItem("StorageLiterVar");
var TankaDatumVar = localStorage.getItem("StorageDatumVar");

var arrayKostnad = [];
var arrayLiter = [];
var arrayDatum = [];
arrayKostnad.push(TankaKostnadVar,);
arrayLiter.push(TankaLiterVar,);
arrayDatum.push(TankaDatumVar,);
document.write(arrayLiter,arrayKostnad,arrayDatum); //Ignore this, just test

//This is the code where the user is writing and it saves to localStorage.
//Html page 1 that saves the variables
var TankaKostnadVar = document.getElementById("tankaKostnad").value;
var TankaLiterVar = document.getElementById("tankaLiter").value;
var TankaDatumVar = document.getElementById("tankaDatum").value;

localStorage.setItem("StorageKostnadVar", TankaKostnadVar);
localStorage.setItem("StorageLiterVar", TankaLiterVar);
localStorage.setItem("StorageDatumVar", TankaDatumVar);
```

I expect the array to add the variable. So if the user writes an 5 the array should first be [5] then when the user writes an 8 the array should be [5,8]

Comment: Where is the code where you’re taking input from the user? My guess is, you are always reading from localStorage and storing them to the array. Another possibility is, you are initialising your array to [] and inserting values from localStorage, hence newly added values are not in the array. Try making the array variables global.

Comment: yepp my though too, arr.push just append the array, it will not check for anything else.

Comment: You both might be right, is there anyway to clear localstorage? Wait, I'll add the code whit the user. Thanks!

Comment: `localStorage.clear()` will clear all entries in the local storage

Comment: Hmm by clearing localStorage i ended up with empty arrays when refreshing the page a second time.

Comment: And also by making the variables global I did not seem to get my functions to work.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep adding to the array you'll need to push the entire array you're holding in memory up to localStorage after appending a new element. Alos, localStorage only stores string values so if you want to maintain the Array structure you'll have to use `JSON.stringify()` before running `setItem()` and then `JSON.parse()` next time you access those values with `getItem()`.

```
//This is the code where the user is writing and it saves to localStorage.
//Html page 1 that saves the variables
var TankaKostnadVar = document.getElementById("tankaKostnad").value;
var TankaLiterVar = document.getElementById("tankaLiter").value;
var TankaDatumVar = document.getElementById("tankaDatum").value;

localStorage.setItem("StorageKostnadVar", JSON.stringify( [TankaKostnadVar] ));
localStorage.setItem("StorageLiterVar", JSON.stringify( [TankaLiterVar] ));
localStorage.setItem("StorageDatumVar", JSON.stringify( [TankaDatumVar] )); 

//This is html page 2 (gets the items from localhost)
var TankaKostnadVar = localStorage.getItem("StorageKostnadVar");
var TankaLiterVar = localStorage.getItem("StorageLiterVar");
var TankaDatumVar = localStorage.getItem("StorageDatumVar");

var arrayKostnad = JSON.parse(TankaKostnadVar);
var arrayLiter = JSON.parse(TankaLiterVar);
var arrayDatum = JSON.parse(TankaDatumVar);

// Now you have arrays with data, but I don't know what you want to do with them...
// you could add more values like this (still page 2)...

arrayKostnad.push('new value 1')
arrayLiter.push('new value 2')
arrayDatum.push('new value 3')

localStorage.setItem("StorageKostnadVar", JSON.stringify( arrayKostnad ));
localStorage.setItem("StorageLiterVar", JSON.stringify( arrayLiter ));
localStorage.setItem("StorageDatumVar", JSON.stringify( arrayDatum )); 

// now check the values again

var TankaKostnadArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("StorageKostnadVar"));
var TankaLiterArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("StorageLiterVar"));
var TankaDatumArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("StorageDatumVar"));

document.write(TankaKostnadArr, TankaLiterArr, TankaDatumArr)
```

And this is what I would do to clean things up a little...

```
// Import these functions and variables to any file that needs to interact with LocalStorage
var storageKeys = ["StorageKostnadVar","StorageLiterVar","StorageDatumVar"];

function addToArray(key, val, arrObj) {
   arrObj[key].push(val)
}

function storeAllLocalStorage(arrayObject) {
    Object.keys(arrayObject).forEach(key=>{
       localStorage.setItem(key, JSON.stringify(arrayObject[key]));
    })
}


// Use above functions when needed
var storedArrays = storageKeys.reduce((acc,key)=> {
      var val = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(key));
      if (typeof val === 'array') return {...acc, [key]:val};
      return {...acc, [key]:[val]};
},{})

addToArray("StorageKostnadVar", document.getElementById("tankaKostnad").value, storedArrays);
addToArray("StorageLiterVar", document.getElementById("tankaLiter").value, storedArrays);
addToArray("StorageDatumVar", document.getElementById("tankaDatum").value, storedArrays);

storeAllLocalStorage(storedArrays)
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/188575/discussion-on-answer-by-cantuket-my-variables-wont-save-in-the-array-they-get-r). Please remember to update the question and/or answer with any relevant information.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want use JSON, you can save string comma separated and, when necessary, transform the items to numbers. To transform in numbers you can use map function or a for. Localstorage only save strings, so if you need to be back to numbers you need to use JSON.parse or use function parseInt, that is global.

```
//Retrieve saved items from localstorage
var TankaKostnadVar = localStorage.getItem("StorageKostnadVar"); // "1,2"
var TankaLiterVar = localStorage.getItem("StorageLiterVar");
var TankaDatumVar = localStorage.getItem("StorageDatumVar");

TankaKostnadVar += "," + document.getElementById("tankaKostnad").value;
TankaLiterVar   += "," + document.getElementById("tankaLiter").value;
TankaDatumVar   += "," + document.getElementById("tankaDatum").value;

localStorage.setItem("StorageKostnadVar", TankaKostnadVar);
localStorage.setItem("StorageLiterVar", TankaLiterVar);
localStorage.setItem("StorageDatumVar", TankaDatumVar);

// if you want to transform TankaKostnadVar and others two, just do like this
TankaKostnadVar.split(','); // result: ['1', '2']

// if you want to transform to number
TankaKostnadVar = TankaKostnadVar.split(',').map( function(number) { 
    return parseInt(number) 
} );
```

The split function of string, breaks a strings in parts separated by one string. In this case, breaks a string separated with comma. So "1,2" turns into ['1', '2'].

Answer (score 0):

You are simply using `localStorage.setItem` which saves your values with the given `key`. If the key exists, it will replace the value. Before you do a `.setItem`, get the value from the local storage first, then parse it to array so that you can finally push the new user inputs to that parsed array. Then you can `.setItem` to replace the "outdated" value from the localStorage.

**UPDATE** Example:

Sorry for leaving this hangin without an example. Here it is:

```
// Get array from local storage
const stringifiedArray = localStorage.getItem('myCollection');

// If there is no 'myCollection' from localStorage, make an empty array
const myCollection = stringifiedArray ? JSON.Parse(stringifiedArray) : [];

myCollection.push('My new item added'); // update array
localStorage.setItem('myCollection', JSON.stringify(myCollection)); // save
```

Comment: Oh, I think I get it, thanks for answer I will try my best!

Comment: @OlleBurman Sorry I left the answer hangin' without an example. Please see the update.

Comment: Oh thanks! The thing is that if you repeat doing this but changing the new item added from "my new item added" to "my new item added again" This will not save the "my new item added" item in the array. It will just overwrite with "my new item addad again" do you understand what i mean? I've not found a solution for this in days. Starting to lose hope and might leave this project soon. :(

Comment: What exactly did you repeat? (Looking at the example code as analogy) Did you do another `myCollection.push(''my new item added again")` after the first `.push` and then `localStorage.setItem...` ? Make sure you have the updated array first before you push your `''my new item added again"` and save.